# Running a Script using a filename

Tags: scripts

I have a script which reads a txt file line by line but it first enters the script asks for the file then reads it.
I want to run the script directly.
Now few files like a.txt and b.txt 
is there anyway to directly run my script along the filename
something like
a.txt(read.sh)

Answer (score 3):

```
./script.sh a.txt
```

and your script will have a.txt in the variable `$1` (`$0` holds the name of the script).

Example:

```
~$ more script
#!/bin/bash
echo $1
~$ ./script a.txt
a.txt
./script "a a".txt
a a.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

If your script *"asks for the file then reads it"* from the terminal's standard input stream (using the shell's built in `read` command for example), then the way to pass a filename to it directly **without modifying the script** would be

```
echo a.txt | ./scriptname
```

or

```
printf '%s\n' a.txt | ./scriptname
```